# Set radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set the value of the radio button via javascript. But I am not being able to do so. What I tried to do was have 4 radio buttons one of which is already selected. If I select some other radio button and click on Refresh, default radio button should be selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/Un8XK/1/

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="x" data-theme="a" />
    <label for="x" style="color: White">X</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="y" onclick="axisonoff(this)" data-theme="a" />
    <label for="y" style="color: White">Y</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="z" data-theme="a" />
    <label for="z" >Z</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="none" data-theme="a" />
    <label for="none" style="color: White">None</label>
</fieldset>


<button id = "Refresh" value="Refresh">Refresh</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#none").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh"); // if this line is not present initially then it works for the 1st refresh. 

});

$("#Refresh").click(function(){
        $("#x").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#y").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#z").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    $("#none").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

I am sure that I have missed something very small but not able to figure out why this approach is not working.

Tools used: Javascript,Jquery 1.9 and JQuery mobile 1.3

Thanks,

Deeksha

Comment: I believe the checked value is <div checked="checked">, not true or false - so you want to use $('#x').prop("checked", "checked")

Comment: @jqueryrocks–there is no checked attribute for [div elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-div-element). There is a checked attribute for radio buttons and checkboxes. It's a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) that has no value.

Comment: Not sure why I used a div there - <input checked="checked">, not <div>

Comment: @jqueryrocks - nope, `.prop("check",true);` sets it, `false` unsets it. - and it is for radio buttons of course. - that `attr()` would get the text value of the original which would NOT be the same as the property.

Comment: NOTE: do NOT do `.removeProp('checked')` as that would prevent resetting the property - use the true/false.

Comment: it's checked="checked" - here's the w3c document: http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-RADIO.html

Comment: @jqueryrocks–instead of linking to a 10 year old, non–normative article, you should instead read the [HTML5 link provided above](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute), or the [HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-checked). The use of values for boolean attributes was introduced for compatibility with XML, it has never been required or necessary in HTML.

Comment: Fair enough - old bad habit I guess!  Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `prop` over `attr` when dealing with boolean attributes.

`.attr("checked", false)` will add `checked="false"` to your element.
In HTML, `<input checked="false" .../>` is the same as `<input checked="true" .../>` or simply `<input checked .../>` as the attribute simply needs to be present on the element for it to be active.

See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KmYqn/).

Change your code to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$("#none").prop("checked", false)...
```

Here is a fixed version of your JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Un8XK/8/

Answer (score 0):

What you have missed is that there is no need for script. Simply use a form with a reset button:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" checked>0<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">3<br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

If you really **must** use script, you can simply return the radio buttons to their default by adding a button to the form:

```
<input type="button" onclick="reset(this.form.radio);" value="Script reset">
```

and a function:

```
<script>
function reset(els) {
    for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        els[i].checked = els[i].defaultChecked;
    }
}
</script>
```